# How can i install Ansible AWX In azure kubernetes service?

Tags: ansible-awx

I have created K8s Cluster. Now in that cluster there are 2 nodes and in each pod there are 30 pods.
I want to install Ansible awx in of the pod.  How to do it.

Answer (score 0):

The standard way to install AWX in kubernetes is via [awx-operator](https://github.com/ansible/awx-operator#basic-install). This works in azure AKS as well.